# How to import a python class from a file in a different folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following file structure:

```
├───common
│       hdfs.py
│       impala.py
│       pandasUtils.py
│       proxy.py
│       stringUtils.py
│       __init__.py
│
├───tests
│   └───unitTests
│           test_stringUtils.py
│           __init__.py
```

From `tests/unitTests/test_stringUtils.py`, I want to import the file `common/stringUtils.py`

I tried the following:

```
import unittest
from common.stringUtils import StringUtils
```

But I have the following error: Unable to import 'common.stringUtils'.

Is there a way to import a file without dealing with sys path or doing anything different from "import from" ?(30 years and still looks like an early access game)

Comment: from common import stringUtils than use stringUtils.StringUtils  ?

Comment: Doesn't this work in your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: import sys
sys.path.append("..") # Adds higher directory to python modules path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PYTHONPATH`. For example

```
PYTHONPATH=. python tests/unitTests/test_stringUtils.py
```

or

```
PYTHONPATH=.. python unitTests/test_stringUtils.py
```

Comment: More generally, `common` is a package you want to use from the test script. Ensure that the directly *containing* `common` is on your Python path.

Comment: With frim common.stringUtils, this works fine. But isn't there a way to NOT have to say "hey use this path" ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain Well, you can put it into the Python package folder which is already in `PYTHONPATH` technically. Or, you should use `sys.path`. Either way, you should tell Python where files are.